# How to select single item from each group from p-multiselect dropdown from Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I have `P-multiselect` group dropdown need to select one value from each group. How to pick that value?

[image]

Comment: Just share a stackblitz with you issue replicate, and expected result, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Please delete the bottom answer and add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global option array = ridePreferenceOptions;

/** For Example: **/

ridePreferenceOptions = [{ label: '', value: '', items: [] }];

// enter code here

onPreferenceSelect(data) {

    // Multiselect array = data.value
    let selected = data.value;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.ridePreferenceOptions.length; i++) {

        let ramp = this.ridePreferenceOptions[i].items.filter(element => element.value == data.itemValue); // Check which selected value in which group present

        if (ramp.length > 0) {

            for (let j = 0; j < this.ridePreferenceOptions[i].items.length; j++) {

                if (this.ridePreferenceOptions[i].items[j].value != data.itemValue) { // Avoid selected value , and remove another one

                    let tempPreference = data.value.indexOf(this.ridePreferenceOptions[i].items[j].value); // Find the index of already selected i.e previous selected value from particular group

                    if (tempPreference >= 0) {
                        data.value.splice(tempPreference, 1); // Delete that index value
                        selected = data.value; // bind current selected
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    this.manualBookingForm.controls.ridePreference.setValue(selected);

}
```